# SVG Uncaught TypeError when using Snap.Select

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Note that I do not get this error when I have my svg code inline my HTML file. 
I have many svg files I need to use within my HTML so it will be terribly inconvenient to have it all within one file.

Within one of my JavaScript functions, here is the code I use:

```
var svgT = Snap("#redBar");
var line = svgT.select("#line");  // exception occurs here
```

Here is the svg code for reference in its own file:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="redBar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 113.9 3.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 113.9 3.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);}
</style>
<g id="line">

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="1.239177e-04" y1="29.3381" x2="113.9399" y2="29.3381" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 1.3293 0 -37.1699)">
        <stop  offset="1.075269e-02" style="stop-color:#EC1C24"/>
        <stop  offset="0.1548" style="stop-color:#EC2026"/>
        <stop  offset="0.2961" style="stop-color:#ED2C2A"/>
        <stop  offset="0.436" style="stop-color:#EE3F32"/>
        <stop  offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#EF4B37"/>
        <stop  offset="0.5483" style="stop-color:#EE4334"/>
        <stop  offset="0.7058" style="stop-color:#ED2D2B"/>
        <stop  offset="0.8586" style="stop-color:#EC2026"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#EC1C24"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <path class="st0" d="M113,3.7H1c-0.5,0-1-0.4-1-1L0,1c0-0.5,0.4-1,1-1l112,0c0.5,0,1,0.4,1,1v1.7C113.9,3.2,113.5,3.7,113,3.7z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Now, when I run the function in JavaScript to select the group element (#line), I get this exception:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of 'select' of null`

It seems that I must do something else to be able to read the elements properly from the svg.

Has anyone dealt with manipulating an svg file with Snap.svg that can give me a tip on something else to try?

EDIT:

I also tried using `Snap.load()` on the windows onload function.

```
var svgT;
var line;
window.onload = function() {
    Snap.load("/svg/RedBar-01.svg", function (f) {
        var g = f.select("g");
        svgT = Snap("#redBar");
        line = svgT.select("#line");
    });
```

I tried to use the `Snap.animate()` on a button click after loading:

```
line.animate({
                fill: "pink",
                transform: 't0,0'
            }, 1000);
```

I don't seem to get any response from the .animate() function at this point though.

EDIT 2:

My current JS code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    Snap.load("/svg/RedBar-01.svg", function (f) {
        var s = Snap(800,800);
        s.append(f);
        var l = Snap("#redBar");

        var line = l.select("#line");
        line.animate({
                fill: "pink",
                transform: 't0,0'
            }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: How are you referencing the svg file if its not inline ? The problem is that Snap can't find that svg element, so you need to clarify how you are loading it, or referencing it.

Comment: @Ian Well I figured the function call `Snap(/*elementID*/)` is the way I reference it. I should have mentioned that I also tried `Snap.load()`. I will edit the post.

Comment: You won't be able to Snap() it until you 'append()' it (you can select from the fragment f though), so try appending (f) after the load to an svg element somewhere. So first create your paper, eg var s = Snap(800,800) or var s = Snap('#somesvgelementsomewherealreadyonthepage') and then s.append(f) in your load callback. Then you should be able to select it.

Comment: @Ian Not sure if I followed your instruction correctly. What I did: `var s = Snap(800,800); s.append(f); var l = Snap("#redBar"); var line = l.select("#line"); line.animate({ fill: "pink" }, 1000);` I am not getting any exceptions but the color doesnt change to pink when loading page. Am I using a wrong variable on something?

Comment: It's not clear if you are doing the load or whatever, maybe add an edit to the bottom.

Comment: @Ian just added another edit. Thanks so much for taking time to help me out.

Comment: @Ian I just deleted the css part of the svg code and it appears the color changes now. I think its all figured out now. If you would like, create an answer, because I think your tips were quite helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you append() the svg fragment f that is loaded.

The general format is

```
var s = Snap(800,800); // or Snap('#mySvg') an existing svg element, not a div

Snap.load( filename, function( fragment ) {
    s.append( f ); //add the loaded svg fragment into the DOM
    var element = s.select('#myId');
    element.animate(....)
});
```

Also make sure there isn't some css styling superceding the svg attributes.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!